# How to validate TextFields in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I was wondering how to validate a simple login form with 2 text fields with a constant value:

ex.
Username: "name"
Password: "pw"

I'm just trying to test segueing to the next page with a login button submission. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On login button click method, check the text of both textfields & if they are correct then navigate to next screen by segue.

```
@IBAction func btn_LoginClicked(sender: AnyObject)
{
 if(txtUsername.text == "name" && txtPassword.text == "pw" )
  {
 //make segue
  }
else
{
  //show alert with wrong credentials.
}

}
```

Comment: @poojathrot -- the question asked in swift ,can you customize your answer in swift it is hopeful for the user

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an API for this kinda thing. Although it does a few things more. But you can definitely use it for your own case.

You can find its code at [SSValidatoinTextField](https://github.com/shamasshahid/SSValidationTextField)

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple

```
@IBAction func btnLoginTapped(sender: AnyObject){

if txtUsername.text.isEmpty() || txtPassword.text.isEmpty(){

//Show Error AlertController
}else if txtUsername.text == "name" && txtPassword.text == "pass"{
//Mark Segue
}

}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I'm looking for